# Java: How do I convert InputStream to GZIPInputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, gzipinputstream

I have a method like

```
      public void put(@Nonnull final InputStream inputStream, @Nonnull final String uniqueId) throws PersistenceException {
        // a.) create gzip of inputStream
        final GZIPInputStream zipInputStream;
        try {
            zipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new PersistenceException("Persistence Service could not received input stream to persist for " + uniqueId);
        }
```

I wan to convert the `inputStream` into `zipInputStream`, what is the way to do that?

- The above method is incorrect and throws Exception as "Not a Zip Format"

converting Java Streams to me are really confusing and I do not make them right

Comment: Why do you think that the provided `InputStream` returns GZIP content? The exception message clearly tells it is not. What exactly is the concrete functional requirement? Why exactly do you need to "convert" it this way?

Comment: I need to save the document on `Amazon S3` in compressed format to save space and reduced billing, which is why the inputstream is a document that I am trying to ZIP and send to `S3`

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I've posted an answer. In the future questions, please don't forget to clearly state the concrete functional requirement. Try to ask how to solve a problem, not how to achieve a solution of which you thought that it's the right solution to the concrete problem. Otherwise the question would likely never receive a valid answer and you keep stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 12):

The [`GZIPInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) is to be used to **decompress** an incoming [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). To compress an incoming `InputStream` using GZIP, you basically need to write it to a [`GZIPOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html).

You can get a new `InputStream` out of it if you use [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to write gzipped content to a `byte[]` and [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to turn a `byte[]` into an `InputStream`.

So, basically:

```
public void put(@Nonnull final InputStream inputStream, @Nonnull final String uniqueId) throws PersistenceException {
    final InputStream zipInputStream;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOutput = new GZIPOutputStream(bytesOutput);

        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            for (int length = 0; (length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                gzipOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            try { inputStream.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
            try { gzipOutput.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        }

        zipInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesOutput.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new PersistenceException("Persistence Service could not received input stream to persist for " + uniqueId);
    }

    // ...
```

You can if necessary replace the `ByteArrayOutputStream`/`ByteArrayInputStream` by a `FileOuputStream`/`FileInputStream` on a temporary file as created by `File#createTempFile()`, especially if those streams can contain large data which might overflow machine's available memory when used concurrently.

Answer (score 5):

[GZIPInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) is for *reading* gzip-encoding content.

If your goal is to take a regular input stream and compress it in the GZIP format, then you need to write those bytes to a [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html).

See also [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189791/4249).