# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/length code

Tags: java, base64

I have decompressed base64 string of 3 document(1 .docx and 2 .pdf) and I am trying to convert these string back to their document. Here is the code I am trying. This code worked for .docx string but not for .pdf string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
    String outputFilePath = "document.pdf";
    File file = new File(outputFilePath);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(file_name_containing_compressed_base64_string), "utf-8");
    byte[] zipData = Base64.decodeBase64(str);
    GZIPInputStream zi = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipData));
    IOUtils.copy(zi, fos);

    fos.close();
    zi.close();

}
```

and I am getting exception on line `IOUtils.copy(zi, fos);` Exception for one .pdf string is

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/length code
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
at com.fileHandling.FileOutput.main(FileOutput.java:126)
```

and exception for 2nd .pdf string is

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
at com.fileHandling.FileOutput.main(FileOutput.java:126)
```

Please suggest me reasons for these exceptions and how can I resolve these exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Your path of processing datas is then:

- file_name_containing_decompressed_base64_string
- => decodeBase64 => zipData  (compressed or not ?)

**- => GZIPInputStream : you want to decompress already-decompressed ?**

- copy to PDF

**The GZIPInputStream is to be used to decompress an incoming InputStream.**

1 easy solution : I would remove the decompressing, but incoherent with the name : *zipdata*.

2 step by step: do a program with every step: coding/decoding, compress/decompress, and check at each step, and put some println/trace

Some other posts about that:  [Java: How do I convert InputStream to GZIPInputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322073/java-how-do-i-convert-inputstream-to-gzipinputstream)

Comment: zipData  is  compressed. So 'GZIPInputStream' is used to decompressed it

Comment: then the name is bad : file_name_containing_decompressed_base64_string

Comment: then solution 2: step by step.